# Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'

Tags: android, parse-platform

Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.

The above error pops up everywhere when I add a Google Maps Activity to a basic Parse.com Note App.

Answer (score 0):

Set your compile and target version to 19 and your min SDK to whatever version you need.

Next you have to adjust your imports to the version that is compatible with the SDKs that you have chosen to compile for. For example if you want to use the v7 support library on sdk 19 you must import it like this: compile compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'

Answer (score 0):

The Google Map Activity updated the build.gradle file. The following dependencies fixed the issue:
`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.5.1.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}`